# Cannot connect to Apache Server -- 301 and " server certificate does NOT include an ID"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl-certificate, http-status-code-301

I have installed XAMPP and using the chrome addon PostMan to test interaction using my computers ip address to access as:

```
http://(ip-address):4430/ServerName/
```

I within my index.php file, there is a simple initailization code for MySQL as:

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "root"; 
$dbName = "dbname";

$db = new MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
```

and result as:

```
$sql22 = "select * from users";

$out = NULL;
if ($result22 = $db->query($sql22))
{
    if($row = $db->fetchObject($result22))
    {
        $row->first_name;
        //json_encode($row);
    }

}
```

Upon using PostMan, `GET` on `http://(ip-address):4430/ServerName/`, nothing appears in the result set, but in the `access.log` displays:

```
[06/Nov/2015:20:37:05 -0500] "GET /ServerName HTTP/1.1" 301 353 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
```

and `error.log`:

```
 www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

I have set the `Listen` ports away from 80, to 4430 and 8000, as is often the issue, but the error persists...

How can this issue be alleviated?

Comment: Default port for https is 443. Your original issue with server SSL certificate.

Comment: Yes, but I never had a problem with this before and adding `echo` statements return results...

Comment: Check your virtualhosts

Comment: `ServerName` should be equal to `openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -subject` output

Comment: where is this executed?

Comment: ask your server administrator about this :)

Comment: @vp_arth It had nothing to do with SSL, just using a 3rd party outdated library, instead of standard PHP methods...no toruble now, :)